# Unable to connect MSQL on Static IP Remotely

Tags: java, mysql, toad

I am trying to connect to **Mysql** from **java**
I am using **Mysql 5.5** and I can access it remotely within the local network.But when I put that System on **Static Ip** I can't connect to Mysql remotely.

I able to connect to **Mysql port**  and I already check for is firewall block that port but no such issue was found.

I also checked using Toad.

Any special setting need for that please help me..
Thanks in advance.

// Edited
Error Message

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Static_IP' (10061)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "put that server on Static Ip"?

Comment: check if the user you are using to connect to mysql, has permission to connect from all ip s. The user should have a host entry like `%` in mysql.user table

Comment: As Subin mentioned you could be facing a allowed hosts problem or it could be a network routing problem. PLease post the complete error message you are getting so we can analyse it.

Comment: What error messages you are getting?

Comment: @Subin I already added this permission thats why I able to connect in my intranet but not on Internet.

Comment: @SachinD you should post the error message you are getting

Comment: I edited question... please see there

Comment: thry this forum http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,415071,415071#msg-415071

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please share stack trace of exception

Try Following solutions :

1. Make sure that MySQL Conncetor for java is included in your class path.
2. Try this sample code :

Declare class variables :

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://ip_address:port_name/db_name";
static final String USER = "username";
static final String PASS = "password";
```

Sample code to create database connection :

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

// STEP 1: Register JDBC driver
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

// STEP 2: Open a connection
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

// STEP 3: Execute a query
System.out.println("Creating statement...");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Then iterate rs to fetch the rows

Comment: thanks for response but I wanted to know how to connect mysql over internet.